# Use a string as an argument in StringReader

Tags: wonderware

I'm using scripting with `.NET` in `Wonderware Archestra IDE`. This works fine:

```
dim SR as System.IO.StringReader;
SR = new System.IO.StringReader(OPCClient_L09.Valve.AliasDatabase);
```

But I need like this and it's not work:

```
dim SR as System.IO.StringReader;
dim Input as String;
Input = "OPCClient_L09.Valve.AliasDatabase";
SR = new System.IO.StringReader(Input);
```

Answer (score 1):

You've declared a String type, which is the Wonderware String type. StringReader is expecting a System.String (i.e. the .NET type).

Change your String declaration to System.String:

```
dim SR as System.IO.StringReader;
dim Input as System.String;
Input = "OPCClient_L09.Valve.AliasDatabase";
SR = new System.IO.StringReader(Input);
```